# Alfresco webscript can't find Company Home folder

Tags: http-status-code-404, alfresco

I'm trying to create a custom webscript on Alfresco Community. I'm following this tutorial: http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/ws-folderListing-intro.html.

Everything works out fine in the beginning. When I navigate to

```
localhost:8080/alfresco/service/
```

and click on 'Refresh webscripts', my new webscript is registered.

But now when I navigate to

```
localhost:8080/alfresco/service/dir/Company%20Home
```

I get the following message:

```
The Web Script /alfresco/service/dir/Company Home has responded with a status of 404 - Not Found.

404 Description:     Requested resource is not available.

Message:    Folder Company Home not found.
Server: Community v4.2.0 (r63893-b12) schema 6.033
Time:   21-mei-2014 17:04:59

Diagnostics:    Inspect Web Script (org/example/dir.get)
```

What is going wrong? I followed all the steps in the tutorial precisely.

Comment: Please post your web script controller code so we can take a look.

Comment: It's exactly the same webscript controller as on this page: http://docs.alfresco.com/community/tasks/ws-controller-create.html . It's named 'dir.get.js'.

Comment: Doesn't that script already start from Company Home?

Comment: No you need to specify a folder as seen here: http://docs.alfresco.com/community/tasks/ws-register.html

Answer (score 3):

Check if you are using a different language then EN in your OS because Alfresco will translate all default folders's names depends in what language are used in your OS in my case am using French so there's no  `Company Home` but there's `Espace Racine`.

About the listing folders API, there's no reason to do a web script for that because it's already exist by default in Alfresco under the path:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/sample/folder/Company%20Home.
```

Comment: IIRC if you use the QName path then that should always be the same, it's only the regular name that gets localised

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you hit the bug: [Need to know why 'companyhome' scope object not available in Workflow Script API](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-1720)

Comment: So tired of hitting bugs with Alfresco. Is there any way to fix this? Can I maybe locate another folder to test the webscript on?

Comment: This bug affected version 3.3.1 of Alfresco which is *very old*. I doubt that even in 2014 it still applied to the then current version of Alfresco.